JavaScript ES6 modules import from CDN library
I have a custom JavaScript file in my theme which handles some logic for external iframe (not exactly iframe tag but a custom element) loading. Normally, I would declare the CDN or JS file in theme.libraries.yml or mymodule.libraries.yml, e.g.:
tableau-embedding-api:
version: 1.0
js:
  https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.min.js: { type: external, attributes: { type: module } } # Adding type module since it is export module
dependencies:
- core/drupal
- core/jquery
- core/drupalSettings
- core/once

But I am unable to find a way to access the exported modules in my custom js file where I use the above library as dependency:
tableau-embedding-api:
version: 1.0
js:
  js/custom.js: {}
dependencies:
- core/drupal
- core/jquery
- core/drupalSettings
- core/once
- mytheme/tableau-embedding-api

And custom.js is:
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
   Drupal.behaviors.my_custom = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
         once('program_insights_page', '.main-section-program-insights').forEach(function(element) {
            // I want to access exported modules by the CDN here.
            // For instance, the above link exports TableauEventType module.
         });
      }
   };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);

The only way I found is to include
import {TableauEventType} from 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.min.js at the top of custom.js and then I can access TableauEventType in attach function which seems not so Drupal way and clean because I need might need to change the embed code and version in different environments.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you
